# what is the difference between creating a web application and a web site?

Tags: asp.net

Why does an assembly get created when I am building a web site? I mean a web site and not a web application.

Comment: You should clarify that you are talking about ASP.NET Visual Studio projects.

Comment: What assembly? I've just created new website with Visual Studio 2010 and there's no DLL or EXE anywhere. So please explain the question better..

Comment: When we have to place the files on production server, we need to copy the assembly of the web site on the production server, where can I get my web site's assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is quite big. A web site is not compiled. Code is placed in the `App_Code` folder and dynamically compiled by ASP.NET at runtime. A web application is precompiled meaning that you can place code wherever you want and it will produce an assembly at compile-time. You also get a project file .csproj associated with it.

Here's an [overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5).

Comment: +1 for explanation, however I believe Chandan is also asking about the dll folder in the bin directory of the website, is this to do with automatic precompilation possibly for debugging?

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani, it is generated at runtime by the ASP.NET engine and it located in a temporary folder: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Comment: No I have compiled the web site and I dont see any dll in the temp folder

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani, you cannot compile a website. A web site is automatically compiled by the ASP.NET engine when a request arrives. You can compile a web application. When deploying your web site you deploy only the .aspx pages and any source code you might have written in the `App_Code` folder. ASP.NET will take care of dynamically compiling it.

Comment: AAAhhhhh!!!!! .....but I have read on msdn website that whether web app or web site, we need to copy the dll on the production server!!!

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani, with a Web Site you don't need to copy any DLL at all. Try it for yourself and you will see :-) Maybe what you have read suggests pre-compiling your web site using the *Publish* functionality in Visual Studio.

Comment: I wonder why I cant host the web site. I am getting some error